# Strange wireless speed variation in terms of distance!

Tags: router, wireless

For some time I noticed that my ultrabook Lenovo Thinkpad experiences a faster decrease in speed, in terms of distance from the router, as other devices. I tested (with speedtest.net) and these are the results (the following values are the approximated averages of download and upload speeds (download ~= upload anyways); also I didn't repeat the tests many times and they might not be accurate, but the problem is persistent!).

```
 Device           |      2 meters      | 4 meters + 1 wall  | 8 meters + 2 walls 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Lenovo Thinkpad  |      50 Mbps       |      30 Mbps       |      1.5 Mbps
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sony Xperia phone|      35 Mbps       |      30 Mbps       |       25 Mbps
```

Note that on a mid-range HP laptop the speed tends to vary in the phone's fashion (I can't make the tests on it right now; that is based purely on observation). When i download something being 8 meters away on the troubling device, it seems like every centimeter counts! Let's say I download something with 200kb/s, if I move 20 centimeters closer in the router's direction, the speed might go up to 300kb/s or even more! What might be the problem? Is the problem on the router's side (a mid-range TP-LINK) or is it on the laptop's side (hardware or software)? Can I fix it? (it bothers me when I try to watch videos) If not, I am quite curious what causes the problem anyways, because as far as I know, this is really, really strange!

Comment: Questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are specifically off-topic for this forum. Please see the Help Center for which types of question are allowed, and which types are not allowed. You can try to ask on Super User.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a difference in the Wifi technology in the client devices. In most cases devices using the 5GHz frequency range (802.11a, n and ac) have a much better throughput (transfer speed) but a much shorter range, than devices operating in the 2.4GHz range (802.11b, g and n).

For example I have 2 smartphones. One is newer and uses 5GHz(with 802.11n) and downloads faster, but drops out once I move more than 2 rooms away. The older phone uses 2.4GHz(with 802.11g) and can still get WiFi in the street.

The frequency set and 802.11 standard used depends on the device's WiFi hardware, the WiFi router's capabilities, and what settings have been applied in both.

Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11) for more info about Wifi.